# Samba connection refused

Tags: networking, server, samba

I am runnung Xubuntu 19.04 and I have a problem with my samba server and basically I can't access it by typing

```
thunar smb://192.XXX.X.X
```

it gives this error: `Connection refused`
I made sure samba is running and `testparm` output show no errors.
I can access the files on windows but not on my linux laptop.
I can succesfully ping the server (if that's relevent) but 
however i can access the file with network option on thunar.
But not for so long until an other error appears.
Either way i am just curious about why i can't access te he server from it's IP and it used to work just fine until it shutdown and once I restarted it i got this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can your append to your question, the output of a few things?  The contents of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, the output of `systemctl status smbd`, the output of `ifconfig`, and the output of `journalctl -u smbd -b`, all as run from your server.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i don"t know how to ssh to my server. [EDIT] nevermind bare with me i'm working on it

Comment: It turns out that i was using ssh on my own laptop.But how would I ssh to my server if it has the same IP

Comment: I'm a bit confused:  Are you trying to make a SMB connection from your computer, to your computer?

Comment: Well, i have setup my server and it was working fine until it decided to turn off.Once it's turned on again and I try to connect i have this error.Ican't ssh to the server because it has the same Ip as the one it's connected from (u know what I am saying ?)

Comment: Ah.  Generally speaking, each device on a network needs it's own address, and this is assigned via DHCP.  If your server and have the same IP, when you issue the `ssh  192.xxx.xx.x` command you will simply connect to the local machine.  Similarly if you try to `thunar smb://192.xxx.xx.x` it will go no further than the local machine.